# How to print json response which is in debug area(Xcode) onto view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift3

I am new to iOS. I have database. Basically I'm retrieving data from a html link(json response) which is stored in array and I have been able to print it in debug area. I want that response to show up on another view controller which should act like button.

**This is our android app.**
As soon as we login and if login is successful we will get response which is in 2nd image "wadi" and "hingna".
And number of response depends on username. Some username may have 1 while others can have many. So that should act like button.

[Android image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BA8j.png)

[Android image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chuNS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a array variable in next view controller and while navigating from one view controller to other view controller pass that array

For example:-

let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

Swift 2+

let mapViewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapViewControllerIdentifier") as? MapViewController
mapViewControllerObj.array = jsonarray self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObj!, animated: true)